# How to replicate input fields on click of button angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I'm facing the problem to replicate input fields onclick of a button
*I have few input fields and i can fill the data in that
*After filling the input fields i have a different data set to add so i need same fields.
*If i press button (addMore) the fields should replicate and it should allow me to add one more set of data.
*There should be one button(remove) that will help me to remonessessaryve those replicated fields if its not necessary.

I have tried this in angular ..and I'm sharing my sample code and plunker plz help me out

**template.ts**

```
<div class="card">
  <input type="text" id="name" value="" class="form-control">
  <label for="form1">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="mobile" value="" class="form-control">
  <label for="form1">Mobile</label>
</div>

<button type="button" title="Add"class="btn btn-sm" 
(click)="addMore">Add</button>
```

**test.component.ts**

```
export class App {

  addMore() {
    //function to replicate the form input fields
  }
```

plunker link :- http://plnkr.co/edit/GCCnoMkLynpELwaYX11m?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for generating dynamic inputs using **`ngFor`**

You can initially create an array with initial value as follows,

```
 inputelements = [{name: '',mobile:''}];
```

on click of addmore button you can push more elements and those will be rendered using **`ngFor`**

Template code will be,

```
  <div class="card" *ngFor="let word of inputelements; let in=index" class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="form1">Name</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputelements[in].name"  class="form-control"  required>
          <label for="form1">Mobile</label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputelements[in].mobile"  class="form-control"  required>

      </div>
  </div>
 <br>
<button type="button" title="Add"class="btn btn-sm pull-right" 
(click)="addMore()">Add</button>
```

**[`WORKING DEMO`](http://plnkr.co/edit/A51B3VHjQbc83TWTIgyL?p=preview)**

Comment: perfect ..@Sajeetharan .thanks bro ..If i need to remove the added fields i can do it by array indexing right??

Comment: @DeepakVijay yes you can remove by passing index and use splice

Answer (score 1):

Keep the track of the inputs with an array and add/remove with js :

```
  inputs = [];

  add() {
    this.inputs.splice(0,0,this.inputs.length+1);
  }
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ylUMOwi7ZdZPjG3cgxs3?p=preview)